# How do I run a function by a single worker, not by all workers in my Gunicorn app?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a gunicorn flask app on docker. There is a load_artifacts function that pulls artifacts from an S3 bucket and saves it to the docker volume. I only want to run this function once during the deployment of the app. But I have multiple gunicorn workers (4) and threads. Looking in the logs it seems like each of the workers is running this function, but I only want one of these workers to run this process.

Is there a way I can have multiple workers but only have a single worker run my function during deployment?

I tried running with a single worker but I need multiple workers for performance reasons

I tried adding logic that checks if the s3 file is already exists in the volume, but the file is quite big (400mb) so this doesn't stop other works from triggering the process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's not foolproof but I have used a file as a lock for this purpose in the past:

```py
import contextlib
from pathlib import Path


class FileLockContextManager:
    """Create a file on enter and remove that file on exit."""

    def __init__(self, filename) -> None:
        self.filename = filename
        self.lock_file = Path(self.filename)

    def __enter__(self) -> None:
        # Might raise FileExistsError
        self.lock_file.touch(exist_ok=False)

    def __exit__(
        self,
        exc_type,
        exc_val,
        exc_tb,
    ) -> None:
        logger.warning("Deleting lock file")
        self.lock_file.unlink()


# Use it like so
try:
    with FileLockContextManager("/my/lock.file"):
        download_from_s3()
except FileExistsError:
    print("Not the first worker to touch the file")
```

I would be interested to know whether there are any downsides to this or any ways to improve it.

Comment: I am using a similar solution, but with a key at redis, instead of a file, for a flask website. It was working well while the website had few users, but now, with tens of thousands of requests every day, some requests arrive with a difference of only 1 or 2 miliseconds, that is not enough to create the key at redis, then two processes run the same task, that is not desired. I am also looking for more robust solution, without having to use Celery.